# NetSuite SuiteTalk single use coupon issue

Tags: soap, netsuite

I briefly tried to use the search feature to find my answers but I did not find much. So I am using the SOAP API, version 2014.1. I am able to create an order with multi-use promotion codes after searching for the promotion. However, I run into issues with single-use coupon codes. Using the single use coupon for search is not a problem. I can find the proper coupon code internal id and promotion internal id but the Order Creation API will not accept.

If I set the promoCode field with the promo internalId then it asks me for a coupon code. However, there is no field for me to place the coupon code or the coupon internalId. If I use the coupon code internalId as the promoCode internalId then it states invalid key or ref for promoCode #### with couponCode ####.

Does the SOAP api support single-use coupon codes? Is it possible that this works with 2015.2? I would have to modify some code due to the nature of WSDLs to support it so I haven't upgraded.

Thanks for any help has a I spent many frustrating hours trying to figure thi

Comment: The 2015.2 endpoint doesn't appear to have it either. When you construct your record ref what happens if you put the coupon code in as the name and the promo internalid in as the internalid?

Comment: I tried just about every combination like this with no luck. It also doesn't seem to make sense for it to work like that. As the name field is the actual name of promotion.

Comment: have you filed a case?

Comment: Yes, I filed a case. They verified and it created a bug to be fixed. May be a long time before it is included into a release. I ended up solving this issue using SuiteTalk to trigger after the insertion of an order that would look at a custom field for a single use coupon code. It then finds the correct internal id for the coupon code and applies it to the order.

Comment: Yes. I've had to do that sort of thing all over the place. Sorry I didn't think to suggest it earlier in the month.